# How to add basic authentication for prometheus (running on docker container) UI/dashboard?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus

I have created a prometheus docker container with the following `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
```

`prometheus/prometheus.yml`

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: monitoring
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - host.docker.internal:8000
```

It was working fine and I was able to view the prometheus UI/dashboard in the following URL

`http://localhost:9090/graph`

Now I need to add a basic authentication for the prometheus UI/dashboard. so that only users with valid credentials can access the UI.

I have referred this [github issue](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/1255) and add the following configuration to the `prometheus/prometheus.yml` file

```
server:
  extraArgs:
    web.config.file: /etc/config/web_config.yml
  probeHeaders:
    - name: Authorization
      value: Basic <'username:password' in base64> 

serverFiles:
  web.config.yml:
    basic_auth_users:
      <username>: '<bcrypt password>'
```

I have replaced `<'username:password' in base64>` with the base64 encoded string `admin:password` and `<username>` with `admin` `<bcrypt password>` with base64 encoded string `password` which is the password of the user.

my `prometheus/web_config.yml` file:

```
basic_auth_users:
  admin: <base64 password>
```

when I run the `docker-compose up` command I get the following error:

```
caller=main.go:455 level=error msg="Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml)" file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml err="parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 12: field server 
not found in type config.plain\n  line 19: field serverFiles not found in type config.plain"
```

Answer (score 4):

The guidance you're following refers to a Helm Chart template (for Kubernetes) which has misled you for your need (Docker Compose).

`basic_auth_users` requires the user (!) in plaintext as a key and the base64-encoded password (only!) as the value.

See [... Using Basic Auth](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/basic-auth/).

Create a second file in your host's `./prometheus` folder:

`web.yml`:

```
basic_auth_users:
    admin: {base64-encoded password}
```

Then, add the flag `--web.config.file` to the Prometheus container image when you run Docker Compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    volumes:
    - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
    command:
    - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    - --web.config.file=/etc/prometheus/web.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
```

Comment: After adding this, I'm getting this error ```caller=main.go:455 level=error msg="Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml)" file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml err="parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 12: field basic_auth_users not found in type config.plain"```

Comment: My apologies. It appears this is a distinct config file. Your existing `promtheus.yml` is unchanged and `--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` and `basic_auth_users` goes in e.g. `web.yml` and needs another flag `--web.config.file=/path/to/web.yml` replacing `/path/to` with the container's (!) path to wherever you've mounted the `web.yml` file.